# List.js default sorting table

Tags: sorting, listjs

I'm using list.js library (http://www.listjs.com/), to sort some tables. I want to know if it is possible to get a default sort when page loads without click nothing.

Answer (score 16):

Lets say you initialize your list like so:

```
var myList = new List('my-list', {
    valueNames: ['mySortableClass1', 'mySortableClass2', 'mySortableClass3']
});
```

Simply call this right after that block:

```
myList.sort("mySortableClass1", {
    order: "desc"
})
```

Comment: Thanks. I wonder why this is not marked as the answer, as it works like a charm!